# Reverse Search NTE

Tags: component-selection

Is there a way to reverse search the NTE site?
I would like to plug in an NTE part number and see the equivalent vendor components. This would give me access to example circuits and development boards.

Answer (score 1):

NTE keeps a stock of relabelled third-party components in the hope of being able to sell them later when the originals have become scarce or discontinued.
For components that are still available elsewhere, NTE is just more expensive without any benefit to you.

So it would not be in NTE's interest to allow you to find out how to go from their stuff to the cheaper originals. You will not find something like the [NTE Cross Reference Chart](http://elecurls.tripod.com/nte.htm) on NTE's site.